# Find and update subdocument, create new one if not exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkupdate

I'm pushing an updateOne query to update (or create if not existent) a subdocument. This is my schema

```
{
    accountData: {
        userId: Number,
        items: [
            {
                itemId: Number,
                purchaseTime: Number
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is an example document

```
{
    accountData: {
        userId: 1,
        items: [
            {
                itemId: 2,
                purchaseTime: 3
            },
            {
                itemId: 3,
                purchaseTime: 5
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run the following bulk query for finding and updating purchaseTime value of itemId's 2 and 4 I get an error. This is the query

```
let bulkQuery = [];
bulkQuery.push({
    updateOne: {
        filter: {
            'accountData.userId': 1,
            'accountData.items.itemId': 2
        },
        update: {
            $inc: {
                'accountData.items.$.purchaseTime': 1
            }
        },
        upsert: true,
        setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
});

bulkQuery.push({
    updateOne: {
        filter: {
            'accountData.userId': 1,
            'accountData.items.itemId': 4
        },
        update: {
            $inc: {
                'accountData.items.$.purchaseTime': 1
            }
        },
        upsert: true,
        setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
});

MyModel.bulkWrite(bulkQuery);
```

The expected change on the document I provided is increasing purchaseTime of itemId=2 from 3 to 4 and adding a new item object with itemId=4 and purchaseTime=1. However, when I run this, I get the following error

> BulkWriteError: The positional operator did not find the match needed
>   from the query. Unexpanded update: accountData.items.$.purchaseTime

Comment: Remove the `upsert` option. You cannot use achieve this in a single query. You have to use two queries one with `$push` and the other with `$inc` operator.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I'm using upsert in another query to update document and create it if it's not existent. Why is it different here?

Comment: `upsert` part is only beneficial for the document doesn't find within `filter` condition i.e. it creates a new document if no document with that criteria exists. But not with the nested document. For the nested one you have to use two queries.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzletI removed upsert and added 2 objects in update; $push and $inc but all it does is creates empty items[] if it doesn't exist. It doesn't populate it.

Comment: Yes that's what I am telling you. Use two queries `$push` and `$inc` without `upsert`.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yeah, it kind of works that way but it has it's own issue as well. When running $push or $addToSet before $inc, it creates a new object even if there is an item with that id.